# Cross compilation errors: linux kernel for PPC440GX (taishan config)

Tags: linux-kernel, cross-compiling, powerpc

Compiling the latest linus-git image for PPC440GX (taishan config) I
got the following errors:

```
git describe
v3.10-rc5-219-ga2648eb

Issuing "make V=1 ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=ppc_4xx- oldconfig" where
the config file ".config" is from powerpc/configs/44x gives:

make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=net/wireless
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=lib
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=lib/zlib_inflate
make ARCH=ppc64 -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=arch/powerpc/boot
arch/powerpc/boot/uImage
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/
  ppc_4xx-gcc -m32 -Wp,-MD,arch/powerpc/boot/.treeboot-currituck.o.d
-Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing
-Os -msoft-float -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-builtin -fPIC
-nostdinc -isystem
/opt/eldk-4.2/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-linux/4.2.2/include
-fno-stack-protector -Iarch/powerpc/boot
-I/media/d4fdcf1c-c7f1-419a-8418-3d0e7b1ad883/linux_latest/arch/powerpc/boot
-mcpu=405 -c -o arch/powerpc/boot/treeboot-currituck.o
arch/powerpc/boot/treeboot-currituck.c
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:82: Error: Unrecognized opcode: `mfdcrx'
make[1]: *** [arch/powerpc/boot/treeboot-currituck.o] Error 1
make: *** [uImage] Error 2
```

Question:

1. why is the "mkdir -p arch/powerpc/boot/" repeated so many
   times?
2. what is the cause of error "mfdcrx"?

Any idea what is the cause of error?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, forgotten to update this site, as per this site:

https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/6/15/213

It is a cross-compile toolchain bug.   Instead of using the one from ELDK, now I used the PPC toolchain from:

http://download.ronetix.info/toolchains/powerpc/powerpc-eabi-4.3.3.tar.bz2

and everything went smoothly.   Thanks.